# Accessing Google-Drive using angular2 application?

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I'm trying to integrate google-drive with my angular2 application. What I want to do is to download/view/edit docs of google drive through my application. I'm not able to find any plugin for this. What should I do?

Comment: You might want to check this tutorial about [AngularJS and Drive API](https://github.com/pinoyyid/ngDrive). This will discuss on how to use basic Drive API functionalities on AngularJS, implementing OAuth 2.0 and more.

Comment: For some official samples you can refer to this [Collaborative Todos](https://github.com/googledrive/realtime-tasks), this is a simple todo list based off [TodoMVC](http://todomvc.com/), [AngularJS](https://www.angularjs.org/), and the [Google Drive Realtime API](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime). This documents will cover all things you need know on how to implement realtime collaboration using AngularJS with Drive API. Hope this helps.

Comment: Sumit was asking how to access google-drive by using angular 2, but what you replied were all about angular 1. Not helping here.